# P2Pool twisted error

Tags: p2pool

I need some help to install and configure p2pool.
I run a Debian 7
installed bitcoin and litecoin (getinfo ok)
firewall with open port 3332 3333 8332 8333 9332 9327 9333 9338
installed p2pool and run it with

```
python run_p2pool.py --net litecoin
```

I just keep having this error, googled for it but can't seem to find any correct answers for this.

```
Testing bitcoind RPC connection to 'http://127.0.0.1:3333/' with username 'Litecoinrpc'...
2014-03-16 13:41:47.063358 > Error while checking Bitcoin connection:
2014-03-16 13:41:47.063426 > Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-03-16 13:41:47.063463 > Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The default RPC port for bitcoind is **8332**. Unless you've changed it with the *-rpcport* option, you should be connecting to that port instead.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you confused the P2Pool stratum port with the wallet node RPC port.

If you’ve set the wallet node RPC port to 3333, which by default is stratum port on the P2Pool as im aware, its very likely wrong set RPC credentials in the config of your wallet node.